# Using JS functionality in Ionic App Component TS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Within an Ionic app, I'm trying to call an external JS file's functions in a TS file and am receiving this error: (Line 9 is `labelImage = function(){`)

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9:15)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| export class CloudVision{
|     labelImage = function(){
|         // Creates a client
|         const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();`

I import this JS file at the start of the TS file:

`import { CloudVision } from '../../../vision.js'`

and use it with:

`CloudVision.labelImage()`

Comment: There is a syntax error. Valid JavaScript is always valid TypeScript.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
import * from '../../../vision.js
```

or include it in ionic-li

or look for type definition in typings

Comment: `import * from '../../../vision.js` is a syntax error. Also, the rest of your advice is nonsensical.

Comment: it's not, i use ts all the time, unless the code in the js file has syntax error

Comment: No. `import *  from 'm';` is invalid. What would it mean anyway?

Comment: means import everything that is exported from that file

Comment: And how would you refer to it? It is illegal. You may only `import * as name from 'm';` I also fail to see what it has to do with the question being asked.